# Remove occasional first name initial in APA citation

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am a newbie to LaTeX and using Overleaf to conduct my project.

Here is my settings for references

```
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{SchoolColor}{rgb}{0.6471, 0.1098, 0.1882} % Crimson
\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.6471, 0.1098, 0.1882} % for chapter numbers
\definecolor{citecolor}{rgb}{0.2, 0.2, 0.6}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=darkblue,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=darkblue,
}
% Use biblatex for references - change style= as appropriate
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,sorting=nyt,style=apa,apamaxprtauth=7]{biblatex}
% \renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}

% add your references to this file
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

And `references.bib`:

```
@article{wang2015pm2,
  title={PM$_{2.5}$ and cardiovascular diseases in the elderly: an overview},
  author={Wang, Chenchen and Tu, Yifan and Yu, Zongliang and Lu, Rongzhu},
  journal={International journal of environmental research and public health},
  volume={12},
  number={7},
  pages={8187--8197},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute}
}

@article{xing2016impact,
  title={The impact of PM$_{2.5}$ on the human respiratory system},
  author={Xing, YuFei and Xu, YueHua and Shi, MinHua and Lian, YiXin},
  journal={Journal of thoracic disease},
  volume={8},
  number={1},
  pages={E69},
  year={2016},
  publisher={AME Publications}
}
```

And usage:

```
cardiovascular diseases \citep{wang2015pm2} and respiratory-related diseases \citep{xing2016impact}
```

Output:

> cardiovascular diseases (C. Wang et al., 2015) and respiratory-related diseases (Xing et al., 2016)

I am confused why the first one is marked by "C. Wang et al.", while the second is marked by "Xing et al."? How to set the first one to "Wang et al."?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Does your bibliography maybe contain 2 or more publications with a first-listed author whose surname is `Wang`, but only one publication whose first-listed author's surname is `Xing`?

Comment: If there are several authors with the same family name APA style requires (in certain situations) that an initial be added to make it clear which author wrote which work: https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/citing-authors-same-surname. Since `biblatex` is an automatic system "several authors" may well mean several versions of the same person's name (e.g. `Don Knuth` vs `Donald Knuth`: both refer to the same person, but they would be treated as different names).

Comment: Note that the code you've provided outputs "Wang et al.", not "C. Wang et al.". It would appear that your full document contains at least two publications whose first-listed author's surname is `Wang`.

Comment: Not really relevant, but if you select `style=apa,` you should not specify a `sorting` option. `style=apa,` comes with its own sorting template that is subtly different from `sorting=nyt,` in some places.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I've checked my bib, there are indeed two publications starting with Wang, many thanks for your help!

Comment: @moewe thanks for your help. I will remove the sorting option. Thanks again for your prompt response.

Answer (score 2):

APA style requires that given name initials be added for people with the same family name in certain situations (namely if both occur as first authors). See https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/citing-authors-same-surname.

Assuming that you have several works by different people called `Wang` as first authors, the output you report is correct. But if you cite only the two entries shown in the question, there is no first name initial in the citations.

Note that `biblatex` cannot tell that different versions of the same person's name refer to the same person. So `Don Knuth`, `Donald Knuth` and `Donald E. Knuth` will all be treated as different names, even though *we* know they all refer to the same person.

In theory this feature can be turned off by setting

```
uniquename=false,
```

but then you would no longer be using correct APA style. (And more generally it is not guaranteed that all 'standard' style options work the same way for `biblatex-apa`, but this one does.)